# Implementation of lookup for persistent retrieval in Matlab

Tags: matlab, hashtable, lookup

My question has several parts.

1. Is a hash table the most useful way to do this in matlab?
2. Is there a way to store the key value pairs and not write them each time the function is called?
3. As for implementing, I was going to write the hashtable in a separate script file as a function call that with each iteration of the loop when the ID changes to return the module "friendly" name. Is this the most efficient way?

Some background first, I have a Key(name) which can have 3 numerical identifiers. My application reads in an XML file from a data logger loops through the IDs and writes out information about the module with that id. The IDs are not reader friendly so I want to associate them to the module name. containers.map won't work as it is a 1-key to 1-value. I'm looking at utilizing the java hash table functionality available in Matlab. There are only about 50 modules each having 3 ids.

The code below is where i started with containers.map and relates to the question of is generating the map/hashtable/key-value pairs each time called the most efficient way?

```
function moduleName = moduleLookUp(key)

    moduleKeys = {key1, key2, key3};

    moduleValues = [value1 value2 value3];

    m = containers.map(moduleKeys, moduleValues);

    moduleName = m(key);
```

Comment: Are your module keys strings or numbers or something in between?

Comment: They keys(names) are strings, the ids(values) are strings for all intensive purpose (they are an 8 digit hex value in actuality).

The more I think over this, I believe what I'm actually trying to do is pass a value and return a key as keys should be unique.

Comment: This would be clearer with a [mcve] - show a simple expected input/output situation. You also need to define "most useful" - do you want easy to read code, an easy to edit dictionary, something very fast? These factors (and others) will have a bearing on the best method. It may also be important to know which version of MATLAB you are using, please [edit] your question to include these details.